# Unable to fix exception in Looper.java

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-looper

I have an app created for the purpose of auditing the hotels.
This is a method in it. This method is supposed to save the answers that the auditor enters while using the app. The method is:

```
  private void loopQuestions(ViewGroup parent) {

        JSONArray ansArry = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject params;
        String inspectedDate = inspctDate, InspectedBy = "" ;

        try {

            //loop1
            Log.e("Total Child", parent.getChildCount() + "");
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                String header =""; 
                if (child instanceof LinearLayout) {
                    //Support for linearlayout
                    ViewGroup llchild = (LinearLayout) child;


                    //loop 2
                    for (int j = 0; j < llchild.getChildCount(); j++) {
                        View subChild = llchild.getChildAt(j);


                        params = new JSONObject();
                        if (subChild instanceof EditText) {
                            nosOfQustion++;
                            EditText edtText = (EditText) subChild;


                            if (edtText.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Inspected By")) {
                                InspectedBy = getText(edtText.getText().toString().trim());
                            } else {
                                params.put("Question", getText(edtText.getTag().toString()));
                                params.put("Answer", getText(edtText.getText().toString()));
                                params.put("Category", header);
                                ansArry.put(params);
                            }
                        } else if (subChild instanceof Spinner) {
                            nosOfQustion++;
                            Spinner spr = (Spinner) subChild;


                                params.put("Question", getText(spr.getTag().toString()));
                                params.put("Answer", getText(spr.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                                params.put("Category", header);
                                ansArry.put(params);

                        } else if (subChild instanceof RadioButton) {
                            String answer="";

                            if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==edtId_1)
                            {answer= "Yes";}

                            else if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==edtId_2)
                            {answer="No";}

                            params.put("Question", getText(rg.getTag().toString()));
                            params.put("Answer", answer);
                            params.put("Category", header);
                            ansArry.put(params);
                        }

                        else if (subChild instanceof RatingBar) {


                            params.put("Question", getText(ratingBar.getTag().toString()));
                            params.put("Answer", ratingBar.getRating());
                            params.put("Category", header);
                            ansArry.put(params);
                        }

                    }//end inner for loop


                    }
                }


                if (isNewAudit) {
                    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


                    Log.e("auditId", auditId);


                    if (!PropertySelectionPage.selectedCity.equalsIgnoreCase("------Other Cities------")) {
                        if (!InspectedBy.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            System.out.println("JsonObj " + ansArry.toString());


                            datasource.insertAudit(auditId, InspectedBy, inspectedDate, PropertySelectionPage.selectedCity,PropertySelectionPage.selectedProperty, ansArry.toString(), 0, PropertySelectionPage.propAddress.contains("'") ? PropertySelectionPage.propAddress.replace("'", "") : PropertySelectionPage.propAddress, PropertySelectionPage.pID);
                            Log.e("NosOfQuestion", nosOfQustion + "");


                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            getActivity().finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter Inspected By", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select city", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("else auditId", auditId);
                    datasource.deleteAudit(auditId);

                    System.out.println("JsonObj " + ansArry.toString());
                    if (!PropertySelectionPage.selectedCity.equalsIgnoreCase("------Other Cities------")) {
                        if (!InspectedBy.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {


                            datasource.insertAudit(auditId, InspectedBy, inspectedDate, PropertySelectionPage.selectedCity, PropertySelectionPage.selectedProperty, ansArry.toString(), 0, PropertySelectionPage.propAddress, PropertySelectionPage.pID);
                            Log.e(" else NosOfQuestion", nosOfQustion + "");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            getActivity().finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter Inspected By", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please select city", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }


            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

It is called as:

```
public void saveAnswers() {
    loopQuestions(layer1);
}
```

When I try to debug, the debugger  takes me to **Looper.java**. It seems to have a lot of errors.

This is the errors in my logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                        at com.csr.audit.Tab1.loopQuestions(Tab1.java:666)
>                                                                        at com.csr.audit.Tab1.saveAnswers(Tab1.java:623)
>                                                                        at com.csr.audit.Tab1.onOptionsItemSelected(Tab1.java:1018)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2473)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:3350)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:347)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:413)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:63)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:203)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:780)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The stack info clearly shows that the **NullPointerException** is in Tab1.java:666, so what is your problem?

Comment: What is the code of line: 666 in file Tab1.java?

Comment: your edittext is null  when you call for tag it seems (edtText.getTag().toString()); Maybe one of your conditions is failed and it's not been initialized

Comment: @Cao: Code in line 666 is :  if (edtText.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Inspected By")){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite obvious that editText.getTag() return a null value. Hence, you should check your data, a quick fix to avoid the crash is:

```
if(edtText.getTag() == null) return;
if (edtText.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Inspected By")){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But 'break' in place of 'return' did the job for me :)

Comment: The idea is to check null before using. You should check your data instead of using the quick fix, it may lead to some un-preditable errors

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes, that's my pleasure!